# Keep playing animation in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to achieve something [like this](http://roblutter.com) (fading animated arrow at the bottom of the header picture indicating that the user needs to scroll down).
In order to to this I'm planning to use the code below.
The issue is that the animation only plays 1x whereas I would like it to play continuously (in a way that wouldn't take too much resource). See http://jsfiddle.net/ZN3aD/

```
$('.icon').css('display', 'block');
$('.icon').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 0);
$('.icon').animate({ opacity: 0, top: "100px" }, 'slow');
```

Comment: What about a css3 infinite animation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you to use CSS animation:

```
.icon {
    ...
    -webkit-animation: icon 1.2s infinite;
    animation: icon 1.2s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes icon {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 80px;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        top: 100px;
    }
}
@keyframes icon {
    from {
        opacity: 1;
        top: 80px;
    }
    to {
        opacity: 0;
        top: 100px;
    }
}
```

It will work in IE10+.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZN3aD/6/

If you anyway want old browsers support then take a look at James Donnelly answer. Or you can use this code snippet:

```
(function animate() {
    $('.icon').animate({ opacity: 1, top: 80 }, 0)
    .animate({ opacity: 0, top: 100 }, 'slow', animate);
})();
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZN3aD/8/

Comment: Where this doesn't answer the question directly, it is a much lighter method of animation.

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks You are right, I added JS solution also.

Comment: it's funny that the   question specifically says *javascript* .

Comment: @TJ And I'm providing javascript solution (along with recommendation for improvements), don't I? :)

Answer (score 4):

Set it up as a recursive function which calls itself when the animation completes. ([**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZN3aD/3/)).

```
$('.icon').css('display', 'block');

function animate() {
    // jQuery's CSS method should be used instead of an instant animation
    $('.icon').css({ opacity: 1 });

    $('.icon').animate({
        opacity: 0,
        // jQuery handles the units for you, so you can just use a number here
        top: 100
    },'slow', function() {
        // I assume you want the top value to be reset here
        $(this).css({ top: 80 });

        // Call the animate() function again when the animation has completed
        animate();
    });
}

// Trigger the animation initially
animate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
var arwtimer = 0;

$('.icon').css('display', 'block');
$('.icon').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 0);


function pleaseScroll() {
    $('.icon').css({ top: 80 }, 0).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 222);;

    $('.icon').delay(999).animate({ opacity: 0, top: "100px" }, 999);
}

arwtimer = setInterval(pleaseScroll, 4000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rvvb2/

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick. Adding setInterval will repeat the animation placed inside function:

```
     function runAnimation(){

     $('.icon').css('display', 'block');
     $('.icon').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 0);
     $('.icon').animate({ opacity: 0, top: "100px" }, 'slow');

                }

var interval = setInterval(runAnimation,1000);
```

Comment: `setInterval` is definitely not the best idea in this case.

Comment: @Tallmaris Could you explain? setInterval is exactly what to use if using js for this.. just needed some more tweaks to get the wanted effect.. see above answer

Comment: In my opinion it always raises lots of problem, most importantly if you have complex js running on the page. Maybe in a simple case like this is ok, but I always feel uncomfortable. Moreover, I noticed that it tends to behave strangely in various browsers: I remember having a problem in Chrome trying to open a popup which was blocked because the page had a `setInterval` on (some kind of spam detection in Chrome maybe). In general, if there are ways to avoid it (as in here) I'd rather not use it.